# Pygame audio not playing on startup (Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I seem to be having difficulty with executing a pygame program on boot up. I have a raspberry pi 3 model B running the latest versions of the required libraries. I am simply trying to play a wav file through pygame when a button is pressed. I substituted an “led.on” script for the pygame to ensure my program was being started on boot-up and it ran flawlessly. However, when I try to use pygame on boot up it will not play the audio file. Although pygame will play the file in the terminal, it will not play on startup.
I am using crontab to run the program from boot. Using the following line:

`@reboot python /home/pi/test.wav &`

And the python code:

```
from gpiozero import Button

import pygame.mixer

pygame.mixer.init()

song=pygame.mixer.music.load(‘/home/pi/test.wav’)

btn=Button(27)

while True:
    btn.when_pressed=(pygame.mixer.music.play)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You should add a delay before you run the script, otherwise the desktop might not have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your question

```
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

play should be called with () as it's a fn

use

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

for looping the music